# How/where can I get comments from strong players on my gameplay?

Tags: go, teaching

I'd like to get advice from strong go players - let's say amateur 6D+ or pros. What are my options for getting that advice?

I am not necessarily looking for full game reviews, rather comments on one or two turning points in a game.

Comment: So none of the people who put that question on hold is actually interested in go?

Comment: The question is definitely **not unclear**. On SO such a question would be off-topic because it is asking for an *off-site* resource. I am new to this site, but I couldn't find an indication that such a reason applies here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[GoKibitz](https://gokibitz.com/)** is a new website that offers a nice frontend for discussing games. I did not use it myself, but it looks promising.
I have no experience how strong the players are which are commenting regularly, however I saw at least many 1d or 2d comments.

If you are willing to spend money on getting regular full reviews on your games I can highly recommend **[In-seong's Yunguseng Dojang](http://yunguseng.com/)**. It is available for American and European timezone. You are getting lessons and reviews of league matches from high amateur dan players. I participated in the school myself for 1 year.

---

As I am new to this site I am not sure if such an advertisement is considered good practice here. Please comment if it isn't. I am not completely sure if the question already is a good fit for the site, because there can be very many answers providing different resources. Selecting one of them as the one right answer is probably not possible.

Comment: I think what you posted is perfectly fine - and useful - as you are sharing your personal experience as a student. The quality of reviews on the GTL looks muich higher than GoKibitz, but maybe it's just ramping up.

Comment: I fully agree on your GTL vs GoKibitz comment. GoKibitz needs some momentum to attract more players if it wants to establish itself in the Go community.

Comment: Marking this as answer. As the GTL reviews are gone, GoKibitz seems to be the most promising option.

Answer (score 4):

Join a Go club with strong players. Your club mates will give you comments and hints. Visit Go conventions and go to Go tournaments.

If joining a Go club is not practical for you, consider to take some payed Go lessons by a professional player.

Comment: Definitely good options, I am just looking for something "less committed" right now.

Comment: Usually there is no "commitment" in joining a Go club. In Germany and probably in other European countries you just go there when you have time. Usually there is no official membership, since the "clubs" are often very small. I would highly recommend to try it!

Comment: I talked about commitment because I would have to travel to find a player of that level (6D+). Attending a go convention would be neat, but this question is more about finding quick and specific answers.

Answer (score 2):

The [Go Teaching Ladder](https://gtl.xmp.net/) is a good place to get comments on your games.  Unless you're already a dan player, you won't get comments from 6d+ players, but you also don't need them.  Your game will be reviewed by a player several stones stronger than you, and they will be able too see enough of your mistakes to help you get stronger.

Comment: Interesting! How does the GTL validate your rank?

Comment: @Christophe: It doesn't need to - your questions will accurately self-identify you at within a stone or two.

Comment: I registered, but the site says "Requesting a review is currently disabled."

Comment: Unfortunatly this website has just turn off their review system. Others are getting set.

Comment: @Kii ok, thanks. Upvoting as this was still good to know.

Comment: @Christophe anyway their database will still be available

Comment: I just received the GTL newsletter confirming that *the active
part of the GTL was shutting down*

Answer (score 2):

OGS has a [review requests section](https://forums.online-go.com/c/teaching/reviews-requests). I just got a great review there so I'd like to share the link.

Answer (score 1):

Some Go tournaments will feature professional commentators who will also play several ["simultaneous" games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/do-strong-go-players-play-simuls-like-in-chess-do-they-ever-play-blindfolded) with players, typically for a small fee, such as $10 or $20 a head. They will remember the salient points of those games and point out the most egregious errors.

These professional commentators also observe and comment on games, but typically only if you are 1-2 dan or higher.